# Align colorbar with figures

Tags: python, subplot, colorbar

I'd like to plot a different color bar at the end of each row without ruining the alignment of the figures. I was able to add the color bars but it messes up the alignment of the figures. I've already tried using the constrained layout in hopes of preserving the alignment but it didn't work out. On a side note, it works perfectly fine when using `add_axes` but I find it too brute.

Here's a sample script for the plots:

```
crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=6, figsize=(20, 13),
                          subplot_kw={'projection': crs})

axlist = axarr.flatten()
for ax in axlist:
    plot_background(ax)

    axlist[0].contourf(lon, lat, t1['tas1'].sel(month=1), cmap='temp6',
                           transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    for i in np.arange(1,6):
        axlist[i].contourf(lon, lat, t_b['tas'+str(i)].sel(month=1),10, cmap='temp6',
                           vmin=-6,vmax=5,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    for i, num in enumerate(np.arange(7,12)):
        axlist[num].contourf(lon, lat, t1['tas'+str(i+1)].sel(month=1),10, cmap='temp6',
                           vmin=0.3,vmax=1.8,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    for i, num in enumerate(np.arange(13,18)):
        axlist[num].contourf(lon, lat, t2['tas'+str(i+1)].sel(month=1), cmap='temp6',
                           vmin=0.3,vmax=1.8,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    for i, num in enumerate(np.arange(19,24)):
        m = axlist[num].contourf(lon, lat, t3['tas'+str(i+1)].sel(month=1), cmap='temp6',
                          vmin=0.2,vmax=1.2,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    for i, num in enumerate(np.arange(25,30)):
        axlist[num].contourf(lon, lat, t4['tas'+str(i+1)].sel(month=1), cmap='temp6',
                           vmin=0.4,vmax=3,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    fig.tight_layout(pad=0.0)

for j in np.arange(1,5):
    fig.delaxes(axarr[j,0])

for i in (5,11,17,23,29):
        plt.colorbar(cs1, ax=axlist[i],extend='both',orientation='vertical', aspect=10)



plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding the following:

```
for i in (5,11,17,23,29):
    pos1= axlist[i].get_position()
    pos2 = [pos1.x0 + 0.27, pos1.y0,  pos1.width / 30.0, pos1.height] 
    cax = fig.add_axes(np.array(pos2)) 
    fig.colorbar(cs1, cax,extend='both',orientation='vertical',aspect=10)
```

will have to change the scalar mappable in `fig.colorbar` but that can easily be solved by looping it once i've set the color limits for the different plots to ensure I've added the correct color bar range.

[image]